# how can i delete a record in sql using more than 1 table

Tags: sql-server-2000

I'm having a problem in sql, can anyone help me
I have 3 tables
sublocation, postingdetail and employee

I have to delete sublocid from sublocation table
but first i have to check that is there any employee working on that sublocation from postingdetail table, if yes then the record shouldn't be deleted.

### table sublocation

sublocid
 sublocname
 mainlocid

## table postingdetail

empid
 subloc
 mainloc

## table employee

empid
 empname
 sublocid
 mainlocid

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
DELETE 
FROM [SUBLOCATION] 
LEFT JOIN [EMPLOYEE] ON [SUBLOCATION].[sublocid] = [EMPLOYEE].[sublocid] 
LEFT JOIN [POSTINGDETAIL] ON [POSTINGDETAIL].[empid] = [EMPLOYEE].[empid] 
WHERE empid IS NULL
```

That might work.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not familiar with sql-server, I am a MySQL user myself, but I know sql-server does have  stored procedures... and that's what stored procedures were made to do...

[Here is a little tutorial on stored procedures.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the meaning of the postingdetail table, and why we are taking the sublocid from table employee rather than postingdetail, but you query should look something like this:

```
delete sublocation
where sublocid not in
(
    select e.sublocid
    from employee e
    join postingdetail p on e.empid = p.emid
)
```